SNS SDK "Program Panicked" when registering a Devnet domain
When trying to get started with the SNS JS SDK, attempting to register a new domain in DEVNET produces an error.
const createDevnetDomain = async () => {

    const [, ixs] = await devnet.bindings.registerDomainName(
        connection,
        "boooooo", // The name of the domain you want to register
        1_000,
        window.solana.publicKey, // PublicKey of fee payer
        getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(NATIVE_MINT, window.solana.publicKey, true), // import from @solana/spl-token
        NATIVE_MINT
    );

    console.log(ixs);

    const tx = new Transaction();
    tx.feePayer = window.solana.publicKey;
    tx.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized')).blockhash;
    tx.add(...ixs);
    console.log(tx);
    const signedTx = await window.solana.signTransaction(tx);
    console.log(signedTx);
    const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTx.serialize());
    console.log(signature);
}



Note: The instruction being generated contains 15 keys and matches the structure of the createNameRegistry() method (https://github.com/Bonfida/sns-sdk/blob/main/js/src/bindings.ts#L77), rather than reflecting those defined for the function being called.

Transaction Instruction being generated IXs:
[
    {
        "keys": [
            {
                "pubkey": "namesLPneVptA9Z5rqUDD9tMTWEJwofgaYwp8cawRkX",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": false
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "5eoDkP6vCQBXqDV9YN2NdUs3nmML3dMRNmEYpiyVNBm2",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": false
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "4sKwnTgwZKjvgNecE7eGPgPw4o6VB2xmH4i2PCVNcTTt",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": true
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "BNVnHvxL2G5Mm1jMD6rEGd8UYLsFY6sXr7ZyP4iXMwth",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": true
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "11111111111111111111111111111111",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": false
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "7NbD1vprif6apthEZAqhRfYuhrqnuderB8qpnfXGCc8H",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": false
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "3Js7k6xYQbvXv6qUYLapYV7Sptfg37Tss9GcAyVEuUqk",
                "isSigner": true,
                "isWritable": true
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "9zZpV9wsCT7AbxcWP4xZxywkPBMq9uL86Vmn6yERAXNT",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": true
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "BmA9Z6FjioHJPpjT39QazZyhDRUdZy2ezwx4GiDdE2u2",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": false
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "3Mnn2fX6rQyUsyELYms1sBJyChWofzSNRoqYzvgMVz5E",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": false
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "J83w4HKfqxwcq3BEMMkPFSppX3gqekLyLJBexebFVkix",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": false
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "CK4GgmwCq1Bcz8dgGSLz5bueJbPdBwNfHPRfWQezgXTU",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": true
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": false
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": false
            },
            {
                "pubkey": "7X2FuvVr3Ji2VpmknqBW1mC4uEo7dapGPHxVARzWf9mR",
                "isSigner": false,
                "isWritable": false
            }
        ],
        "programId": "snshBoEQ9jx4QoHBpZDQPYdNCtw7RMxJvYrKFEhwaPJ",
        "data": [
            13,
            7,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            98,
            111,
            111,
            111,
            111,
            111,
            111,
            232,
            3,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    }
]

The Transaction itself (TX)
{
    "recentBlockhash": "8zsaDAYGJaAtq2WYGiuTZto8biiarKTJCsDapPx3dbfH",
    "feePayer": "3Js7k6xYQbvXv6qUYLapYV7Sptfg37Tss9GcAyVEuUqk",
    "nonceInfo": null,
    "instructions": [
        {
            "keys": [],
            "programId": "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111",
            "data": [
                3,
                160,
                134,
                1,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            ]
        },
        {
            "keys": [],
            "programId": "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111",
            "data": [
                2,
                64,
                13,
                3,
                0
            ]
        },
        {
            "keys": [
                {
                    "pubkey": "namesLPneVptA9Z5rqUDD9tMTWEJwofgaYwp8cawRkX",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "5eoDkP6vCQBXqDV9YN2NdUs3nmML3dMRNmEYpiyVNBm2",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "4sKwnTgwZKjvgNecE7eGPgPw4o6VB2xmH4i2PCVNcTTt",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": true
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "BNVnHvxL2G5Mm1jMD6rEGd8UYLsFY6sXr7ZyP4iXMwth",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": true
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "11111111111111111111111111111111",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "7NbD1vprif6apthEZAqhRfYuhrqnuderB8qpnfXGCc8H",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "3Js7k6xYQbvXv6qUYLapYV7Sptfg37Tss9GcAyVEuUqk",
                    "isSigner": true,
                    "isWritable": true
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "9zZpV9wsCT7AbxcWP4xZxywkPBMq9uL86Vmn6yERAXNT",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": true
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "BmA9Z6FjioHJPpjT39QazZyhDRUdZy2ezwx4GiDdE2u2",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "3Mnn2fX6rQyUsyELYms1sBJyChWofzSNRoqYzvgMVz5E",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "J83w4HKfqxwcq3BEMMkPFSppX3gqekLyLJBexebFVkix",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "CK4GgmwCq1Bcz8dgGSLz5bueJbPdBwNfHPRfWQezgXTU",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": true
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                },
                {
                    "pubkey": "7X2FuvVr3Ji2VpmknqBW1mC4uEo7dapGPHxVARzWf9mR",
                    "isSigner": false,
                    "isWritable": false
                }
            ],
            "programId": "snshBoEQ9jx4QoHBpZDQPYdNCtw7RMxJvYrKFEhwaPJ",
            "data": [
                13,
                7,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                98,
                111,
                111,
                111,
                111,
                111,
                111,
                232,
                3,
                0,
                0,
                0
            ]
        }
    ],
    "signers": [
        "3Js7k6xYQbvXv6qUYLapYV7Sptfg37Tss9GcAyVEuUqk"
    ]
}


RPC Network call Payload:
{
    "method": "sendTransaction",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "params": [
        "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",
        {
            "encoding": "base64",
            "preflightCommitment": "finalized"
        }
    ],
    "id": "2cade21a-5a69-434d-b27a-1b84372cd000"
}


**FULL RESPONSE FROM RPC **
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "code": -32002,
        "message": "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: Program failed to complete",
        "data": {
            "accounts": null,
            "err": {
                "InstructionError": [
                    2,
                    "ProgramFailedToComplete"
                ]
            },
            "innerInstructions": null,
            "logs": [
                "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
                "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
                "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
                "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
                "Program snshBoEQ9jx4QoHBpZDQPYdNCtw7RMxJvYrKFEhwaPJ invoke [1]",
                "Program log: Entrypoint",
                "Program log: Beginning processing",
                "Program log: Instruction unpacked",
                "Program log: Instruction: Create v3",
                "Program log: Found product in mapping.",
                "Program log: Found correct price account in product.",
                "Program log: panicked at 'range end index 165 out of range for slice of length 0', src/state.rs:131:19",
                "Program snshBoEQ9jx4QoHBpZDQPYdNCtw7RMxJvYrKFEhwaPJ consumed 47020 of 199700 compute units",
                "Program snshBoEQ9jx4QoHBpZDQPYdNCtw7RMxJvYrKFEhwaPJ failed: SBF program panicked"
            ],
            "returnData": null,
            "unitsConsumed": 47320
        }
    },
    "id": "2cade21a-5a69-434d-b27a-1b84372cd000"
}

UPDATE:
After creating ATAs for wSOL, I am now getting a different error ( Insufficient funds )
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "code": -32002,
        "message": "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1",
        "data": {
            "accounts": null,
            "err": {
                "InstructionError": [
                    0,
                    {
                        "Custom": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            "innerInstructions": null,
            "logs": [
                "Program snshBoEQ9jx4QoHBpZDQPYdNCtw7RMxJvYrKFEhwaPJ invoke [1]",
                "Program log: Entrypoint",
                "Program log: Beginning processing",
                "Program log: Instruction unpacked",
                "Program log: Instruction: Create v3",
                "Program log: Found product in mapping.",
                "Program log: Found correct price account in product.",
                "Program log: Pyth FP32 price value: 550826466",
                "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
                "Program log: Instruction: Transfer",
                "Program log: Error: insufficient funds",
                "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4302 of 147304 compute units",
                "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: custom program error: 0x1",
                "Program snshBoEQ9jx4QoHBpZDQPYdNCtw7RMxJvYrKFEhwaPJ consumed 56998 of 200000 compute units",
                "Program snshBoEQ9jx4QoHBpZDQPYdNCtw7RMxJvYrKFEhwaPJ failed: custom program error: 0x1"
            ],
            "returnData": null,
            "unitsConsumed": 56998
        }
    },
    "id": "dcdd3973-2329-4498-9497-297f4a139be2"
}


Solution: TLDR; Create a wSOL ATA and fund it.
I had to write the answer and replicate the steps to realize what the solution was :-p
I got a clue when I extracted the instruction getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(), it returned an account that according to the explorer, did not exist.


I had to load the KeyPair, So I have it in the Phantom Wallet, but also configured in the Solana CLI config:
solana config set --keypair <Path to my KeyPair> 
solana balance 
spl-token balance So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112


Then I used the CLI to wrap Sol since the Phantom wallet doesn't provide that functionality. ( replace the 1 with some valid amount based on your regular SOL balance in Devnet for that wallet. )
So I airdropped some more SOL to it, and then wrapped it to get wSol.

spl-token --url devnet wrap 1 

Output: (This ATA is from my previous wallet)
Wrapping 1 SOL into Knzf7k5tHxYBqtpANNNnzDD37hPHEUT4FumNY18LQA6

Signature: 3y6AGbUxyjXEskmkGd5bLgxbEFc7166MrYf6CDVSHVmvgvwSz4HLceusWvfmVzL39SdN4AYx4gxGFCandQG91dLF



Now The account was Initialized and had wSol on it.

Then I retried, Signed the Transaction ( with the Phantom Wallet )

Went to check the TX Signature and it worked:

https://explorer.solana.com/tx/hzsxSa8PopAc4z3NukxJSGgHp8u4u8S6LpJXDnDBn2s6L2TspM4oG45Lh9aiCR29865zKBJ3rbDaT3pDqQ4cmkF?cluster=devnet
##EXTRA TIP: Verifying the Domain. ##
Now, I wen and checked the Transaction and could not find the Domain anywhere, it worked but I could not tell which Publick Key was the domain name.
So I remembered the devnet.bindings.* had several other methods and used this one devnet.bindings.getDomainKeySync('my-domain-name')
const pubkey = devnet.utils.getDomainKeySync(domainName);
   


Then, using the Domain Public Key to check if the domain name is the one I registered:
const domainKey = new PublicKey("EmXhygaKUQJbFs37DSdxwtHYgtMgQdp4e6Pnk1QkPsVn");
const domainNameReverse = await devnet.utils.reverseLookup(connection, domainKey);
console.log(domainNameReverse);


